# Выделение нужного слова жирным в php?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть допустим три буквы:

$st = 'ком';

Есть фраза:

$string = 'компьютерная техника';

Как выделить жирным нужные буквы из переменной $st в переменной $string.

т.е. вот так

'**ком**пьютерная техника'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str_ireplace

Comment: Не работает, скорей всего из за того что старая версия php

Comment: У вас данные в кодировке UTF-8 ?

Comment: да, проверял, не работает(((((

Comment: попробуйте preg_replace('#'.$st.'#ius', '<b>'.$st.'</b>', $string);

Comment: Работает отлично,! СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 3):

```
print(str_replace($st,'<b>'.$st.'</b>',$string));
```

Comment: Спасибо помогли только вот еще какой прикол, а если строка $st = 'ком' а $string = 'Компьютерная техника', то он не выделяется, т.е. есть тут еще влияет значение регистра. 'К' большая, не видит маленькую. Как игнорировать значение регистра,?